# Add a second attribute/category column to Django administrator GUI

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm learning Django right now and I made this class called Clowns. On the Django Admin page I made two test objects.

[image: objects]

I made four attributes(dunno what they're called lol) for clowns. They are title, description, identification, and hobbies. See below:

```
    title =             models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description =       models.TextField()
    identification =    models.CharField(default='-', max_length=5)
    hobbies=            models.TextField()
```

To make the "CLOWN" column you see in the image I added this to the clown class:

```
def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I seem to only be able to do this with one attribute/category, in this case it's title. How do I make another column for another attribute, say identification?

Comment: You want to include the ids of each row right?

Comment: I want to make another column to the table in the Django admin page, showing the identification attribute. I currently have only one, showing the title attribute.

Comment: Can you show your admin class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the admin.py file create custom ModelAdmin for your model clown, and register it

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Clown

class ClownAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'identification', 'hobbies')

admin.site.register(Clown, ClownAdmin)
```